# How to empty data from service?

Tags: angular

I have service where i set data. But problem is that that data is set on all pages. What i want is to empty data when i click on other page. Any suggestion how can i do that?

This is service where i set and get:

```
setCustomer(id, accountClassCode) {
        if(!this.gups.isEmptyObject(this.customer)){
            this.customer.next({ 'id': id, 'accountClassCode': accountClassCode });
        }
     }

     getCustomer() {
         return this.customer.asObservable();
    }
```

In component i get data like this:

```
this.subscription = this.ups.getCustomer().take(1).subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (data.id) {
        if (data.accountClassCode === 'CA') {
            this.fillGridFromSearchPopup({ 'caId': data.id });
        } else if (data.accountClassCode === 'BA') {
            this.fillGridFromSearchPopup({ 'baId': data.id });
        }
    }
});
```

So now on click i wana empty data from service

Comment: If you set the service as a provider at the module level then it will be a singleton across all components in that module.  If you set it as a provider at the component level, it will only be an instance for that component.

Answer (score 0):

On the component that you want to have the data, run an ngOnDestroy. In that method, end the service. The method will run whenever you leave that component, i.e., go to another route. Basically will look like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```